# Why scalar valued functions need execute permission rather than select?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, functions

I am wondering why, for scalar valued function, that I have to grant the user to execute rather than just a select?

meanwhile a table valued functions works just fine with only select permission or `db_datareader` membership.

to be more clear here is my example:
I need a user that has read only permission to the database. 
so I created a user called `testUser` and give it `db_datareader` membership.
then I created a table valued function called `fn_InlineTable`. And all is great. `testUser` runs this SQL all day long

```
select * from dbo.fn_InlineTable
```

then I need a scalar function , so I created a scalar function called `fn_ScalarTest`. 
`testUser` cannot run this SQL

```
Select dbo.fn_ScalarTest(1)
```

Well understandably: it is because I have not given "testUser" permission to execute `fn_ScalarTest`.

My question is: based on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150888/insert-update-delete-with-function-in-sql-server,
that says a `FUNCTION` cannot be used to perform actions that modify the database state. So why not let a scalar function to be used with the same "SELECT" permission rather than execute permission??

I hope my question makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: A follow-on question from this is: What is the best way to grant permission to invoke any function in the database? 
(We would really want this for any user given db_datareader privilege.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most likely the primary reason is that Table-Valued Functions return a Result Set, just like Tables and Views. This means that they can be used in the `FROM` clause (including `JOIN`s and `APPLY`s, etc) of `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` queries. You cannot, however, use a Scalar UDF in any of those contexts.

Secondarily, you can also `EXECUTE` a Scalar UDF. This syntax is quite handy when you have default values specified for input parameters. Take the following UDF, for example:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.OptionalParameterTest (@Param1 INT = 1, @Param2 INT = 2)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @Param1 + @Param2;
END;
```

If you want to treat any of the input parameters as "optional", you still need to pass in the `DEFAULT` keyword when calling it like a function since the signature is fixed:

```sql
DECLARE @Bob1 INT;

SET @Bob1 = dbo.OptionalParameterTest(100, DEFAULT);

SELECT @Bob1;
-- Returns: 102
```

On the other hand, if you `EXECUTE` the function, then you can treat any parameters with a default value as truly optional, just like you can with Stored Procedures. You can pass in the first *n* parameters without specifying parameter names:

```sql
DECLARE @Bob2 INT;

EXEC @Bob2 = dbo.OptionalParameterTest 50;

SELECT @Bob2;
-- Returns: 52
```

You can even skip the first parameter by specifying parameter names, again, just like with Stored Procedures:

```sql
DECLARE @Bob3 INT;

EXEC @Bob3 = dbo.OptionalParameterTest @Param2 = 50;

SELECT @Bob3;
-- Returns: 51
```

**UPDATE**

Why might you want to use the `EXEC` syntax to call a scalar UDF just like a Stored Procedure? Occasionally there are UDFs that are great to have as UDFs since they can be added to a query and operate over the set of rows returned, whereas if the code were in a Stored Procedure then it would need to be placed into a cursor in order to iterate over a set of rows. But then there are times that you want to call that function on a single value, possibly from within another UDF. Calling a UDF for a single value can be done as either:

```sql
SELECT dbo.UDF('some value');
```

in which case you get a return value in a result set (a result set won't work). Or it could be done as follows:

```sql
DECLARE @Dummy INT;

SET @Dummy = dbo.UDF('some value');
```

in which case you need to declare the `@Dummy` variable;

HOWEVER, with the `EXEC` syntax, you can avoid both of those annoyances:

```sql
EXEC dbo.UDF 'some value';
```

ALSO, scalar UDFs have their executions plans cached. This means that it is possible to run into parameter sniffing issues if there are queries in the UDF that have execution plans. For scenarios where it is feasible to use the `EXEC` syntax, then it is possible to also use the `WITH RECOMPILE` option to ignore the plans compiled value *for that execution*. For example:

SETUP:

```
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestUDF (@Something INT)
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Ret INT;
   SELECT @Ret = COUNT(*)
   FROM   sys.indexes si
   WHERE  si.[index_id] = @Something;

   RETURN @Ret;
END;
GO
```

TEST:

```
DECLARE @Val INT;

SET @Val = dbo.TestUDF(1);
SELECT @Val;

EXEC @Val = dbo.TestUDF 0 -- uses compiled value of (1)
SELECT @Val;

EXEC @Val = dbo.TestUDF 0 WITH RECOMPILE; -- uses compiled value of (0)
SELECT @Val;

EXEC @Val = dbo.TestUDF 3 -- uses compiled value of (1)
SELECT @Val;
```

Comment: Excepting that EXEC UDF() is just syntactic sugar for SELECT UDF(). It's not like the one is being executed and the other isn't. Neither can have side-effecting operators. Typical Microsoft.

Comment: And +1 for EXEC UDF() - I didn't know about that, and the extra things it can do

Answer (score 6):

I think the difference in permissions is because you can actually invoke scalar-valued user-defined functions with EXEC just like stored procedures (which I hadn't realized until I dug into SQL Server 2000 Books Online, where they introduced user-defined functions), yet you can't actually select from them as a table source. For example:

```
DECLARE @date datetime
EXEC @date = dbo.first_day_of_month '8/14/2015'
SELECT @date
```

In this case, dbo.first_day_of_month is a user-defined function. I don't know why you would ever invoke a function that way, but I would speculate that they required EXECUTE permission rather than SELECT to maintain consistency. Nowadays it's probably just holding on as compatibility baggage.

Comment: Excepting that EXEC UDF() is just syntactic sugar for SELECT UDF(). It's not like the one is being executed and the other isn't. Neither can have side-effecting operators. Typical Microsoft.

Comment: +1 for "compatibility baggage"